# Глагол в 3 лице, который синонимичен слову «занят»

Tags: синонимы

Сейчас мы думаем над изменением статуса *не беспокоить* на *занят*.

Однако это чревато тем, что в системе нет пола, и мы как бы ориентируемся только на мужчин, хотя женщины, которые пользуются продуктом, тоже есть. Вариант с *занят(а)* сразу отпадает, потому что так мы нигде не пишем.

Собственно говоря, я хочу услышать ваши предложения, как можно заменить это краткое причастие на глагол в 3 лице, который, так сказать, подойдёт и к мужчина, и к женщинам.
Например, «Лиза сейчас играет», «Павел сейчас играет». Глагол в 3 лице — это лучший вариант.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Просит не отвлекать"?

Comment: Вариант хороший, но это слишком длинно и может влезть, скорее всего.

Comment: Просит подождать?

Comment: Нет, это не то.

Comment: Берите в пример Skype, где ваша фраза точно бы была неуместна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткий ответ:
Пишите "занят", ибо это пользователь, а слово пользователь мужского рода.

Длиный ответ:
В русском языке (по крайней мере в формальном) никогда не использовалось склонение/спряжение для совпадения с полом лица, о котором мы говорим. Слова склоняются/спрягаются чтобы совпадать с родом существительного или местоимения, но не с полом. По этой причине, вне зависимости от пола человека, статусы употребляются ко всем одинакого: директор, врач, водитель, кондуктор, механик, игрок, пользователь, пассажир, маляр, художник, пилот, секретарь и т.п.

Естественно имеются такие примеры: учитель/учительница, певец/певица, продавец/продавщица и подобные прочие. Но, опять же, в текстах формальных, официальных, деловых используется основная нейтральная форма, она как правило мужского рода, но бывают и женского. Например, если мужчина специализируется по пошиву одежды, то он швея... а не швей.

Если не хочется странностей типа "Лиза занят" и нет возможности запрограммировать окончания по полу в анкете, то добавляйте существительное или символы грамматики.
"Пользователь Лиза занят"
"Игрок Лиза занят"
"Лиза - занят"
"Лиза: занят"

Comment: Ваш ответ очень подробный, рассуждение интересное и правильное. Однако вы для начала посмотрите на скриншот, который я прикрепил к вопросу, а уж потом говорите. Я это к тому, что у нас не влезут дополнительные слова. Здесь, похоже, нет решения. Ладно, пока ничего менять не будем...

Answer (score 0):

Статус должен показывать, что пользователь сейчас не может/ не хочет играть, да?

Предлагаю:

- "Сейчас/Временно не играет"
- "Сейчас/Временно не в игре"

Comment: Да нет. Нужно показать, что пользователя сейчас не следует беспокоить, и сделать нужно так, как я изложил выше. Плюс должно всё поместится в интерфейс (см. скриншот).

Comment: Помимо всего прочего, пользователь необязательно должен быть именно в игре.Он может быть в сети.

Comment: А чем плох вариант "не беспокоить"?

Comment: А никто и не говорит, что это плохой вариант. Я просто ломаю голову над подбором нужного слова (см. заголовок). Всё. Если ни у кого нет вариантов — тему надо закрывать.